# CSS Drop-down menu z-index issue

Tags: css, z-index, drop-down-menu

The current html and css is a bit messy being that the site is still in early beta and is being developed, but this menu will be used.

http://beta.defiant-guild.net

I have the header and slider both absolutely positioned within a relatively positioned container div. The order of the z-index stack I need from back to front is:

- header
- slider
- menu
- slider image
- menu drop down list

I am open to any ideas to make this simpler or for a fix to this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your problem? Just give them appropriate z-indeces. The higher the value, the further up in the stack it will be. However, it only works on absolute or relative positioned elements. If the css is applied to the drop down menus, and whatever else has an absolute or relative position, all should be fine.